# Value error: time series data can not convert string to float

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series

The below code is not working I am trying to use my timestamp data, aggregate it in 10 minute intervals and do time series analysis in pandas, I am getting a value error on the last command and I dont know how to remediate

```
0       2016-01-01 00:11:52
1       2016-01-01 00:13:00
2       2016-01-01 00:14:49
3       2016-01-01 00:21:00
4       2016-01-01 00:23:05
5       2016-01-01 00:29:00
6       2016-01-01 00:30:00
7       2016-01-01 00:30:36
8       2016-01-01 00:32:00
9       2016-01-01 00:33:00
10      2016-01-01 00:36:40
11      2016-01-01 00:36:55
12      2016-01-01 00:41:00
13      2016-01-01 00:48:17
14      2016-01-01 00:50:49
15      2016-01-01 00:51:00
16      2016-01-01 00:53:00
17      2016-01-01 00:56:00
18      2016-01-01 00:57:00
19      2016-01-01 00:57:35
20      2016-01-01 01:01:00
21      2016-01-01 01:01:37
22      2016-01-01 01:02:07
23      2016-01-01 01:08:32
24      2016-01-01 01:09:00
25      2016-01-01 01:16:00
26      2016-01-01 01:18:47
27      2016-01-01 01:21:00
28      2016-01-01 01:27:34
29      2016-01-01 01:29:07
               ...        
values = series.values
values = values.reshape((len(values), 1))
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler = scaler.fit(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `dtype` is `Timestamp`... if not, do this first

```
series = pd.to_datetime(series)
```

Problem is you need to turn these into numbers that make sense for scaling.
I'd subtract the minimum date from the series to get a series of `Timedelta`s.  Then find the total seconds for each `Timedelta` which is a float.
Now you're ready for `MinMaxScaler`

```
values = series.sub(series.min()).dt.total_seconds().values
values = values.reshape((len(values), 1))
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler = scaler.fit(values)
```

---

***setup for debugging***

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """0       2016-01-01 00:11:52
1       2016-01-01 00:13:00
2       2016-01-01 00:14:49
3       2016-01-01 00:21:00
4       2016-01-01 00:23:05
5       2016-01-01 00:29:00
6       2016-01-01 00:30:00
7       2016-01-01 00:30:36
8       2016-01-01 00:32:00
9       2016-01-01 00:33:00
10      2016-01-01 00:36:40
11      2016-01-01 00:36:55
12      2016-01-01 00:41:00
13      2016-01-01 00:48:17
14      2016-01-01 00:50:49
15      2016-01-01 00:51:00
16      2016-01-01 00:53:00
17      2016-01-01 00:56:00
18      2016-01-01 00:57:00
19      2016-01-01 00:57:35
20      2016-01-01 01:01:00
21      2016-01-01 01:01:37
22      2016-01-01 01:02:07
23      2016-01-01 01:08:32
24      2016-01-01 01:09:00
25      2016-01-01 01:16:00
26      2016-01-01 01:18:47
27      2016-01-01 01:21:00
28      2016-01-01 01:27:34
29      2016-01-01 01:29:07"""

series = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt),
                     sep='\s{2,}', header=None,
                     index_col=0, squeeze=True,
                     engine='python').rename_axis(None)

series = pd.to_datetime(series)

series.sub(series.min()).dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: if i do the first line values=series.sub(series.min()).dt.total_seconds().values i get the error: TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')

Comment: this is what I did, would it be helpful to email you my ipython notebook? I appreciate your help, i just feel very stuck!

Comment: and then when i call the other function `values = series.sub(series.min()).dt.total_seconds().values` i get that same error

Comment: version: '0.18.1'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140015/discussion-between-kwashington122-and-pirsquared).

Comment: @kwashington122 can you copy and paste the code I just pasted below ***setup for debugging*** and run it?

Comment: I dont really understand how that works, if I do that it literally just prints out  
Out[68]:
data1.csv so I dont understand, if there is anyway I can send you my code over messanger or something? let me know please because im running into a block.

Comment: @kwashington122 I'm not referencing `'data1.csv'`!  You should be running `series.sub(series.min()).dt.total_seconds()` at the end.  If you end up with a series of floats, then that implies there is nothing wrong with your python.  And the problem lies in your data or how you are importing it.

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-dbd8a3644636> in <module>()
----> 1 series.sub(series.min()).dt.total_seconds()

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   2670             if name in self._info_axis:
   2671                 return self[name]
-> 2672             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   2673 
   2674     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: when i do series.dtypes i get Value    float64
dtype: object

Comment: this  is what i get when i type in series.dtypes                                  ` Value
login_time 
2016-01-01 00:00:00 3.0
2016-01-01 00:15:00 3.0
2016-01-01 00:30:00 7.0
2016-01-01 00:45:00 7.0
2016-01-01 01:00:00 5.0`

Comment: @kwashington122 ahh... your `series` is not `pd.Series` its a `pd.DataFrame`... you shouldn't have gotten this error with my test code because I ensured it was a `pd.Series`.  You need to run this on the column name.  `series['colname']`  I don't know what the column name is because you didn't include it.

Comment: you can also try `series.sub(series.min()).iloc[:, 0].dt.total_seconds()`

Comment: thank you! i will try this out again right now, if not is there anyway I can send you the data set? or my ipynb? thank you!

Comment: AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line:

```
series = pd.to_datetime(series)
```

before scaling, but it will turn your timestamps to floats. And i dont think it can be meaningfully reversed